# How to set a listbox using Value

Tags: c#

I've got the following code for a listbox of hotkeys (data set abbreviated for this post).

What I'm trying to do is press a key (such as '2') in a listview component and have it set the hotkey listbox to 2.

Thanks for any help.

```
    private void listView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // this line doesn't work !!!
        listBoxHotKeys.SelectedItem = e.KeyChar.ToString();
        e.Handled = true;
    }


    private List<HotKey> comboListHotKey = new List<HotKey>();

                comboListHotKey.Add(new HotKey("0", 48));
            comboListHotKey.Add(new HotKey("1", 49));
            comboListHotKey.Add(new HotKey("2", 50));
            comboListHotKey.Add(new HotKey("3", 51));
            comboListHotKey.Add(new HotKey("4", 52));
        listBoxHotKeys.DataSource = comboListHotKey;
            listBoxHotKeys.DisplayMember = "TextName";


public class HotKey
{
    public HotKey(string textName, uint keyCode)
    {
        TextName = textName;
        KeyCode = keyCode;
    }
    public string TextName { get; set; }
    public uint KeyCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did either of these answers solve your problem?

Comment: you're using win forms or WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
private void listView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int index = listBoxHotKeys.FindString(e.KeyChar.ToString(),-1);   
    if(index != -1)  //-1 index means it did not find an item
        listBoxHotKeys.SetSelected(index,true);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

this is recommended in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9ef2e69(v=vs.90).aspx) MSDN article

Answer (score 0):

This is vb example, but You can convert it :

**Update :** (this work fine)

```
     Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim pp As New List(Of HotKey)
        pp.Add(New HotKey("0", 48))
        pp.Add(New HotKey("1", 49))
        pp.Add(New HotKey("2", 50))
        pp.Add(New HotKey("3", 51))
        pp.Add(New HotKey("4", 52))
        pp.Add(New HotKey("5", 53))
        ListBox1.DataSource = pp
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "TextName"
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "KeyCode"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.KeyPress
        For x = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            Dim pp As HotKey = CType(ListBox1.Items(x), HotKey)
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) = pp.KeyCode Then
                ListBox1.SelectedIndex = x
                e.Handled = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'or just use : ListBox1.SelectedValue = Asc(e.KeyChar) : e.Handled = True
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class HotKey
    Private _name As String
    Private _key As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal textName As String, ByVal keyCode As Integer)
        _name = textName
        _key = keyCode
    End Sub

    Public Property TextName As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property KeyCode As Integer
        Get
            Return _key
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _key = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

To be earnest, lamorach provide You correct answer, but there's need some converting, because `e.KeyChar` return `char` value.

In everyone's solution there are no conversion `e.KeyChar` to `uint` using `Asc` function. Or, I think in `c#` You have to use `(int)e.KeyChar` (I'm not sure, not programming in c#).

Comment: Here is what I've put together based on your response...            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in listBox3DHKHotKeys.Items)
            {
                if (item.KeyCode == e.KeyChar.ToString())
                {
                    listBox3DHKHotKeys.SelectedIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            } but there are errors in the if line...i need to compare the value members, not the text

Comment: @user337447 I updated my answer (solution) and work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the VB code but I cannot convert it. I'm getting too many syntax errors trying to convert it over to C#.

Comment: @user337447 Just use Your posted code and bellow `listBoxHotKeys.DisplayMember = "TextName";` add one more line `listBoxHotKeys.ValueMember = "KeyCode";` and change Your `listBoxHotKeys.SelectedItem = e.KeyChar.ToString();` to `listBoxHotKeys.SelectedValue = (int)e.KeyChar;` ... if this don't work, I give up :(

Comment: That didn't work. That did not select '3' in the list.

Comment: This worked - so thanks everyone:             ch = (char)e.KeyChar;
            listBox3DHKHotKeys.Text = ch.ToString();

Comment: but, that look for `TextName` not for value of `KeyCode`... or I wrong (?!) Try to change `comboListHotKey.Add(new HotKey("3", 51));` to `comboListHotKey.Add(new HotKey("qwe3", 51));` and test again.

Comment: Changing '3' to 'qwe3' does not allow me to press the 3 key to select 3. I want to press one hot key and have the listbox update to what I pressed AND to store the key value to a variable (which it now does with your help). So i changed '3' to 'qwe3' and could no longer press a key to select that in the listbox. Hmmm...maybe this isn't solved yet after all.

Comment: @user337447 That's because by pressing key You *search* `text` of the `item` but not `value`... btw. You can press key `3` but function find nothing so nothing happen.

Comment: @user337447 You have to search for ascii `keycode` which You provide, store in `KeyCode` property of `HotKey` class. In case of key `3` that is ascii code `51`. That is for what You have to search. Defining in `DisplayMember` You set `TextName` (in Your case `3` or in my case `qwe3` ;) ) and in `ValueMember` You set `KeyCode` property of `HotKey` class (there is ascii code, for example, `51` for key/number `3`). So, You have to use `ListBox1.SelectedValue=(int)e.KeyChar;`. it's interesting this one not working, like You said (?). Or maybe there's need some replacement for vb `asc` function.

Answer (score 0):

I would set it just by updating the selected value if you have it.

```
private void listView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    listBoxHotKeys.SelectedValue = e.KeyChar;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I also believe you would need to set the ValueMember of the listbox equal to the item's keyCode.

```
listBoxHotKeys.ValueMember = "KeyCode";
```

Comment: This code will work ok if You convert `e.KeyChar` to `uint`

Comment: listBox3DHKHotKeys.SelectedValue = e.KeyChar; gives me this error: Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty ValueMember. Let me add the valueMember, I don't have that yet.

Comment: @user337447  `listBox3DHKTotKeys.ValueMember = "KeyCode";`  Did You add this line in Your code? You'll get that error if You don't set `ValueMember` for Your `ListBox`.

Comment: @user337447 I not code in `c#` but I think if You use lamorach modified code `listBoxHotKeys.SelectedValue = (int)e.KeyChar;` it will work everything perfectly. And, of course, don't forget to set `ValueMember` ...

Comment: I added ValueMember:

            listBox3DHKHotKeys.DataSource = comboListHotKey;
            listBox3DHKHotKeys.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
here--->    listBox3DHKHotKeys.ValueMember = "ValueName";
            
But then my VS 2013 app wouldn't show my hot key form so I had to remove it. I don't know why that happened.

This line:

            listBox3DHKHotKeys.SelectedValue = e.KeyChar;
            
Still gives the error: Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty ValueMember.

Comment: When I inspect the listBoxHotKeys I don't see my data but on the form the data is in the listbox.

Something is really screwed up in my code and maybe even in the HotKey class file.

Thanks to everyone for trying to help me but I'm really lost now. I need to go back and start this listbox thing from the very beginning, starting with how I create my hotkey data.

Comment: @user337447  One question: Why You, at all, in `HotKey` class use `uint` for `KeyCode` instead `string` or `chr`? ... `e.KeyChar` return `char` value, and You can avoid this conversion to `uint`. btw. You set `listBox3DHKHotKeys.ValueMember = "ValueName";` or  `listBox3DHKHotKeys.ValueMember = "KeyCode";` ?? .... because, in Your class you name that field `KeyCode`, not ValueName.